# Wie kann man dem Kellner sagen, wieviel Trinkgeld man ihm gibt?

Tags: phrase, politeness, idiomaticity

In einem Restaurant ist es gewöhnlich, dem Kellner ein bisschen Trinkgeld zu geben. Mir ist aber unklar, wie ich höflich erklären kann, wieviel Trinkgeld ich gebe.

Sagen wir, dass die Rechnung 19€ ist, und dass ich 20€ geben will. Falls ich einen 20€-Schein habe, kann ich ihn einfach geben und „Stimmt so“ sagen. Gibt’s andere Ausdrücke für „Stimmt so“? Ich habe mehrmals „Geht so“ gesagt, bis mir gesagt wurde, dass es ganz falsch klingt.

Wenn ich aber die präzise Summe, die ich geben will, nicht habe, dann muss ich mehr geben, und Rückgeld bekommen. In diesem Fall muss ich ausdrücklich sagen, wieviel ich gebe. Nehmen wir mal an, dass ich einen 50€-Schein habe. Was kann ich in diesem Fall sagen?

1. Machen wir 20
2. Sagen wir 20
3. Machen Sie 20
4. Nehmen Sie bitte 20
5. Ich bekomme 30 zurück, bitte
6. Ich bezahle 20
7. Ich gebe Ihnen 20
8. Ich lasse Ihnen 20
9. Nehmen Sie bitte einen Euro für sich <del>Sie</del>
10. Da bekommen Sie einen Euro Trinkgeld
11. 20
12. 20, bitte

Wären diese Ausdrücke richtig? Gibt’s andere Möglichkeiten? Wirken die letzten zwei unhöflich?

Comment: Wenn man 20 statt 19 Euro gibt, geht auch _1 € / einer ist für Sie_ oder _das Wechselgeld / den Rest können Sie behalten_ und bei #9 kann man ebenfalls _behalten_ statt _nehmen_ verwenden. Im Süden sagt man m.W. auch _scho(n)_ statt _so_. Statt #5 sage ich manchmal _ich hätte gerne 30 zurück_.

Comment: Wo ich wohne (Vorarlberg) sagt man *Passt scho so* oder *Machama's 20*, falls irgendwann as Ländle bsuacha ko willsch!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es ist ziemlich einfach. Gibt man den passenden Betrag, sagt man schlicht "Stimmt so." oder "Passt so.".

Gibt man mehr als man geben möchte, nennt man schlicht den akkuraten Betrag, also beispielsweise "2,50", "10", "24".

Es gibt in beiden Fällen natürlich viele weitere Möglichkeiten. Überreiche ich zum Beispiel einen 20€-Scheine, stecke mein Portemonnaie ein und wünsche "einen schönen Tag noch", ist es auch offensichtlich, dass ich kein Rückgeld erwarte.

Auch bei der Angabe des akkuraten Betrages, kann ich auch sowas wie "Machste 30 draus." oder "Gibste mir 10 zurück." sagen, oder was auch immer mir beliebt. Dies ist aber alles nicht gang und gäbe.

Answer (score 14):

Wenn ich bei einer 19€-Rechnung 20 € geben möchte (also 1 € Trinkgeld), aber nur einen 50er habe, dann sage ich **"20, bitte"**, d. h. `Nr. 12`.

Comment: Ich stimme zu, mit der Maßgabe dass ich bisweilen auch "Auf 20, bitte" verwende. #12 ist aber völlig in Ordnung.

Comment: "20, bitte" macht aber nicht ganz klar, ob das der zahlende Betrag sein soll oder eine Bitte nach Rückgeld ist. Im zweiten Fall würde man 30.- zahlen wollen  :)

Comment: @potAito Echt? Das ist mir so noch nie passiert. Wenn mir jemand nur 20 € zurückgäbe, würde ich ziemlich verdutzt aus der Wäsche gucken.

Answer (score 1):

Falls man überhaupt kein Geld zurückhaben möchte, kann man auch sagen:

> - Der Rest gehört Ihnen.
> - Passt (so).

Von @Iris:

> - Stimmt (so).

Die anderen Ausdrücke werden wahrscheinlich verstanden. Es kann jedoch bei `11.` und `12.` zu Missverständnissen kommen, da nicht klar ist, was 20 beträgt, das Rückgeld, oder der gezahlte Betrag.

Folgende Sätze würde ich nicht verwenden, was aber auch an mir persönlich liegen kann:

- 7.
- 8.
- 10.

`11.` und `12.` würde ich auch nicht verwenden, was allerdings an der oben beschriebenen Unklarheit liegt.

Comment: Meine Wahl ist 11. Natürlich muss die Intonation stimmen.

Comment: @Iris: Das *liest* man auch! (in der Frage)

Comment: 11 und 12 sind meiner Erfahrung nach absolut üblich. Die Bedenken wegen der Unklarheit sind zwar nachvollziehbar, jedoch erfolgt die Aussage in der Realität i.A. als direkte Antwort auf die Preisangabe des Kellners, wodurch m.E. klarer wird, dass der Gast den Betrag, den der Kellner erhält, nach oben "korrigiert".

Comment: Ich stimme @O.R.Mapper zu, denn im deutschen Sprachraum ist das Aufrunden auf einen glatten Betrag die üblichste Form, das Trinkgeld zu bestimmen. Starre 10%-Regeln o.ä. wie in manchen anderen Ländern sind absolut unüblich. Außerdem passt es zum Rechtsprinzip [_invitatio ad offerendum_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufforderung_zur_Abgabe_eines_Angebots) und zur deutschen Sprachsparsamkeit.

Comment: @Crissov ich habe auch nichts über Trinkgeld an sich gesagt. Ich habe lediglich gesagt, dass man ``11`` und ``12`` falsch verstehen kann. Ich nehme meisten die ``1``

Comment: @Crissov: Ich verstehe ehrlich gesagt nicht so ganz, was Aufrunden damit zu tun hat, ob man sich auf den zu zahlenden Betrag oder das erwartete Rückgeld bezieht.

Comment: @Crissov Auf was runde ich denn auf, wenn ich 21€ zahlen muss? Ich gebe bestimmt nicht 30€.

Comment: Wenn die Rechnung 19 € beträgt und der Gast nichts weiter als „20“ sagt, aber 50 € gibt, dann meint er aufgrund der sozialen Konventionen offensichtlich, dass er 20 € *geben* möchte und nicht, dass er 20 € zurück *bekommen* (also 30 € geben) möchte. Wäre es hingegen üblich, beliebig viel aber mindestens 10% Trinkgeld zu geben, also in diesem Fall 20,90 € oder mehr zu bezahlen, dann müsste die Bedienung abschätzen, ob es sich um einen ungewohnt knauserigen (~ 5%) oder sehr großzügigen (fast 60%) Gast handelt – oder nachfragen.

Comment: @Em1 Wenn man 21€ zahlen muss, wäre es zB üblich 23,- € oder 24,- € zu geben. Aber niemals 23,10 €.

Comment: @raznagul Meine Frage war eher rhetorisch... Es ging mir darum, dass man eben *nicht* einfach aufrundet, denn (mathematisch gesehen) gibt es zu 21€ keinen in der Praxis sinnvoll anwendbaren Wert. 25€ (mathematisch nachvollziehbar) ist in der Praxis selten der Fall. Zudem kommt noch die Frage was "glatt aufgerundet" ist. 21€ ist ja schon glatt, zumindest genau so glatt wie 22-29 auch. Sind diese jedoch nicht "glatt", so ist es folglich 30, was ja abseits von gut und böse ist.

Comment: @Em1 Bei Bargeld meint „glatt aufgerundet“ meist einen Betrag, der in Scheinen bezahlt werden kann, also _n_ × 5 €. Natürlich gibt es auch Fälle, in denen ein Vielfaches der zweifarbigen Münzen (1 € und 2 €) oder der goldenen Münzen (0,10 €, 0,20 € und 0,50 €) oder eines beliebigen größeren Geldscheins gemeint ist, allerdings im Vergleich zu 10 €, 50 € oder 100 € eher selten 20 € oder 200 €.

Comment: @Em1: Rückblickend auf eigene Restaurantbesuche würde ich mutmaßen, dass man beim Trinkgeld üblicherweise auf 50 Cent genau "rundet". Bei einem Gesamtpreis von 21€ bezahlt man so z.B. 22,50€, wenn man mehr als 1€ geben möchte (2€ fände ich bei Gesamtbeträgen unter 30€ schon ziemlich viel). Gleichzeitig sind 50 Cent noch nicht so klein, dass es für den Kellner in Arbeit ausartet, das Wechselgeld herauszusuchen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Volle Zustimmung meinerseits. Genau so ist die Realität.